# Use an integral test to find values of real P, for which the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\ln(n))^P}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Using the integral test, 
$\displaystyle \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{2}^{b} \frac{1}{x(\ln(x))^P}dx$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[\frac{\ln(x)^{(-P+1)}}{-P+1}\right]_{2}^{b} = \displaystyle \lim_{b\to \infty}\left[(\frac{\ln(b)^{-P+1}}{-P+1}) - (\frac{\ln(2)^{-P+1}}{-P+1})\right]$
For convergence, the integral must equal a finite value, which I set as N, and rearranged for P.
$N = \displaystyle (\frac{\ln(b)^{-P+1}}{-P+1}) - (\frac{\ln(2)^{-P+1}}{-P+1})$
$\displaystyle N(1-P) = \ln(b)^{1-P} - \ln(2)^{1-P}$
$\displaystyle (N(1-P))^{1-P} = \ln(b) - \ln(2)$
However, at this point, I was unsure how to  procede, and what to do with the values N and b.

Comment: The concentration test gives the result faster and simpler. Unless it is obligatory to use the integral test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your introducing $N$ and the subsequent algebra are really not so helpful. I suggest you think about the following:

What happens to $\ln(b)$ as $b\to\infty$? Therefore, what happens to $(\ln(b))^{1-P}$? You want to consider the cases $P>1$ and $P<1$.

Note that your formula does not make sense when $P=1$, and so you must treat that case separately.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln x <  x \to \ln^P x <  x^P \to\frac{1}{\ln^P x} > \frac {1}{x^P} \to \frac {1}{\sqrt{x \ln^P x}}> \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{P+1}}}$

RHS is divergent if $P$ is less than or equal to $0$ by $p$-test otherwise we can not conclude any result by using direct comparison.

Comment: There is a typo and your result is certainly not getting you to the result the OP needs. The OP's approach was just fine.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{2}^{b} \frac{1}{x(\ln(x))^P}dx$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[\frac{\ln(x)^{(-P+1)}}{-P+1}\right]_{2}^{b} = \displaystyle \lim_{b\to \infty}\left[(\frac{\ln(b)^{-P+1}}{-P+1}) - (\frac{\ln(2)^{-P+1}}{-P+1})\right]$
If $-p+1>0$ or $p<1$ then   $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to \infty}\ln(b)^{-p+1}\to \infty$ and if $-p+1<0$ or $p>1$then  $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to \infty}\ln(b)^{-p+1}\to 0 $ so if $p>1$ the series  is convergent.